# grep works with \s, but not with \s+

Tags: regex, bash, grep

The following command works with `\s`

```
echo "\"Using Android 10\"" | grep "\".*\sAndroid\s.*\""
```

and prints

```
"Using Android 10"
```

But if add a + as follows:

```
echo "\"Using Android 10\"" | grep "\".*\sAndroid\s+.*\""
```

the pattern stops matching.

What is wrong with `\s+`?

Comment: In basic POSIX regex, \s matches a literal backslash followed by the letter `s`, and a `+` matches a literal `+`.  What do you hope to achieve? Have a look at [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) to see what regex characters you have available. Caveat: GNU `grep` (without other options) interprets the pattern as "extendend regex" (ERE), while on BSD `grep` (i.e. MacOS), the pattern is understood as "basic regex" (BRE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong is the missing backslash in `BRE` aka *Basic Regular Expression*:

```
echo '"Using Android 10"' | grep '".*\sAndroid\s\+.*"'
                                                ^
```

if you prefer to **not** use backslash, use `ERE` aka *Extended REgex*:

```
echo '"Using Android 10"' | grep -E '".*\sAndroid\s+.*"'
```

or using `PCRE` aka *Perl Compatible Regular Expression*:

```
echo '"Using Android 10"' | grep -P '".*\sAndroid\s+.*"'
```

---

If you do support the `-P` switch, this is the most reliable, because `POSIX` ways to do this are:

```
[[:space:]]\+
[[:space:]]{1,}
```

The `\s` is supported by recent versions of `GNU` `grep`.

Comment: `-P` is the best way if you want to use full-fledged regex (PCRE). In this case you do not have to escape regex metasymbols (for example, `+`).

Comment: Looks like I already answered this